# Azure Mass Container security settings change to public (or private)

Tags: azure, containers

i am looking for a way to massively change the securtiy settings of multiple containers within my azure storage. I am looking into several programs (celebrata / Azure Explorer etc.) but so far i am not able to select a list of containers and change the settings for all of them to public (or vise versa to private). Is there a tool out there that can do this?

Or should i just use cloudcopy and let it run over all the containers again with the -P argument, does this actually work? Since cloudcopy does not replace files and might only work when adding new containers.

Anyone any good tips or have had this before, i have thousands of containers and can't go over them one-by-one :-( thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, no tool does that today. You would have to do it yourself. The process is rather simple: You list containers in your storage account, then loop through the list of containers and change the ACL on each container individually. Please see the code below.

```
    private static void ChangeContainerACL()
    {
        var cloudStorageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(accountName, accountKey), true);
        var blobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        BlobContinuationToken token = null;
        do
        {
            var listingResult = blobClient.ListContainersSegmented(token);
            token = listingResult.ContinuationToken;
            var containers = listingResult.Results;
            foreach (var container in containers)
            {
                //Code below assumes that you have not defined any access policies on the blob container. 
                //If that is not the case, then you would need to get permissions on the container by using container.GetPermissions()
                container.SetPermissions(new BlobContainerPermissions()
                {
                    PublicAccess = BlobContainerPublicAccessType.Off
                });
                Console.WriteLine("ACL for " + container.Name + " changed to Off (Private).");
            }
        }
        while (token != null);
        Console.WriteLine("All done...");
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Gaurav, will run a test this evening.